# Ubuntu get stuck on a daily basis

Tags: video, dell, vlc

I'm using Trusty 14.04 and my computer gets frozen on a daily basis. My machine is a laptop, Dell Latitude 3340.

This usually happens when I watch videos on VLC, or when I exit full screen videos (using escape) in websites like YouTube.
It also happens when i scroll or switch between tabs in my browser (chromium).

After the last time my computer got froze I ran

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/kern.log
```

and I noticed this error:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: Unknown ELD version 1
```

Thought it might be related, though I wasn't able to find it's accurate meaning in google. It's also worth mentioning that as far as I'm concerned my Audio works find, other than some popping noise I hear from time to time.

Your help would be appreciated.